# PHPWord set rtf value in a docx template

Tags: php, rtf, phpword

I need to add a rtf string in my docx template and save as .doc or .rtf format using PHPWord lib. I'm using this code below to set values in my variables texts, but when I try to change ${value7} by my variable $rtf which contains rtf string it doesn't work. This works just from ${value1} to ${value6}.

```
foreach ($pacientEvo as $key => $value) {
    $rtf = $pacientEvo[$key]['EVOLUCAO'];
}

$doc = new TemplateProcessor('../../file/Evolucao.docx');
$doc->setValue('${value1}', $pacientName);
$doc->setValue('${value2}', $birthday);
$doc->setValue('${value3}', $pacientProntuary);
$doc->setValue('${value4}', $pacientRegistry);
$doc->setValue('${value5}', $dateEvo);
$doc->setValue('${value6}', $hourEvo);
$doc->setValue('${value7}', $rtf); // It doesn't work.

$doc->saveAs('results/test.rtf');
```

[My rtf string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo9ik.png). Using PHPWord basics sample I can create a rtf file with my $rtf variable. But I need to put a header with other information.

#### Update

When save my template end I try to open it, I recieve a message:

> Error in word to try open file. Try these suggestions:
>
> 1 - verify the file permissions,
>
> 2 - verify if there is free memory and disc space.
>
> And 3 - Open the file in a text conversor recovery".

I guess the error to open .doc or .rtf file happens because the variable $rtf. But I don't know how to fix that. As I measured if I edit my template without $rtf variable or I create a new document with this same variable it works

Comment: ___Doesn't work___ Please be more specific. That is really no help

Comment: _Looking closer_ Do you mean that you only see that LAST value from your `$pacientEvo` array?

Comment: Which message??

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, When save my template end I try to open it, I recieve a message: "Error in word to try open file. Try these suggestions: 1 - verify the file permissions,  2 - verify if there is free memory and disc space. And 3 - Open the file in a text conversor recovery". I guess the error to open .doc or .rtf file happens because the variable $rtf. But I don't know how to fix that. As I measured if I edit my template without $rtf variable or I create a new document with this same variable it works.

Comment: That should ALL have been in the original question